# round a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to round a single column in pandas without affecting the rest of the dataframe?

```
>>> print(df)
  item  value1  value2
0    a    1.12     1.3
1    a    1.50     2.5
2    a    0.10     0.0
3    b    3.30    -1.0
4    b    4.80    -1.0
```

I have tried the following:

```
>>> df.value1.apply(np.round)
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    3
4    5
5    5
```

What is the correct way to make data look like this:

```
  item  value1  value2
0    a       1     1.3
1    a       2     2.5
2    a       0     0.0
3    b       3    -1.0
4    b       5    -1.0
5    c       5     5.0
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You are very close.
You applied the round to the series of values given by `df.value1`.
The return type is thus a Series.
You need to assign that series back to the dataframe (or another dataframe with the same Index).

Also, there is a [`pandas.Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html?highlight=round#pandas.Series.round) method which is basically a short hand for `pandas.Series.apply(np.round)`.

```
>>> df.value1 = df.value1.round()
>>> print df
  item  value1  value2
0    a       1     1.3
1    a       2     2.5
2    a       0     0.0
3    b       3    -1.0
4    b       5    -1.0
```

Comment: Thank you. not feeling very bright for missing this :)

Comment: Pandas does not (to me at least) come naturally. I am fairly sure I worked out how to do this after reading another SO answer last week or so. but I couldn't find it again to mark as duplicate so it may have been a slightly different question.

Comment: @LyndonWhite could one use `df["value1"].round()` ? Also is there are a _round up_ or _round down_ function? And also what about if the column name has a space in it? ie `value 1` - I assume `df.value 1.round()` would fail?

Comment: Looks like you have 3 questions there. Use the ask a question button 3 times.

Comment: You can even round entire dataframe by just saying df.round(). No need to give for each column

Answer (score 86):

For some reason the round() method doesn't work if you have float numbers with many decimal places, but this will.

```
decimals = 2    
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))
```

Comment: df.column_name.round() seems to apply to output formatting. The applying of the lambda actually changes the underlying stored value.

Comment: @StephanDoliov Exactly, precision problem bother me for a  long time. `round()` can only set display precision not stored value.

Comment: This gives SettingWithCopyWarning

Answer (score 34):

Use the [pandas.DataFrame.round()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html?highlight=round#pandas.DataFrame.round) method like this:

```
df = df.round({'value1': 0})
```

Any columns not included will be left as is.

Comment: this is the best answer. if only this had an inplace argument.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner `inplace` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of pandas.

Answer (score 21):

No need to use for loop. It can be directly applied to a column of a dataframe

```
sleepstudy['Reaction'] = sleepstudy['Reaction'].round(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are doing machine learning and use tensorflow, many float are of 'float32', not 'float64', and none of the methods mentioned in this thread likely to work. You will have to first convert to float64 first.

```
x.astype('float')
```

before round(...).

Answer (score 6):

No need to use lambda or creating function. It is straight-forward.
See example below

```
df['decimal_place_2'] = df['decimal_place_2'].round(2)
```

Comment: I think answers to this question needs to be updated... Tx

Answer (score 5):

```
saldo_acred['cumsum_prc_saldo'].astype('float').round(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have both string values as well as decimal values in single columns.

```
def round_2(x):
    try:
        return round(x,2)
    except:
        return x

df['cur_TMIN_IMD_WeekSum']=df['cur_TMIN_IMD_WeekSum'].apply(round_2)
```