# Pandas: how to change the data type of values of a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
actor          Daily Total   actor1  actor2
Day
2019-01-01     25            10       15
2019-01-02     30            15       15
Avg            27.5          12.5     15.0
```

How do I change the data type of 'Avg' row to integer? How do I round those values in the row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133538/round-a-single-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas after add new row filled by floats all columns are changed to `float`s.

Possible solution is [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) and convert all columns:

```
df = df.round().astype(int)
```

Or add new `Series` converted to `integer`:

```
df = df.append(df.mean().rename('Avg').round().astype(int))
print (df)
            Daily Total  actor1  actor2
actor                                  
2019-01-01           25      10      15
2019-01-02           30      15      15
Avg                  28      12      15
```

If want convert only columns with row values filled by whole numbers:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns[df.loc['Avg'] == df.loc['Avg'].astype(int)], 'int')
df = df.astype(d)
print (df)
            Daily Total  actor1  actor2
actor                                  
2019-01-01         25.0    10.0      15
2019-01-02         30.0    15.0      15
Avg                27.5    12.5      15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` to access index then use `numpy.round` in `apply`.

```
import numpy as np

df.loc['Avg'] = df.loc['Avg'].apply(np.round)
```