# How to round the value, python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, rounding

How do I round each row of my dataframe? I have tried looking on so, but cannot seem to find the right solution
I have some code :

```
skrip, si3 = konten(skripsi2, 'proba.sav')
berita1['hasil_sentimen'] = pd.Series(skrip)
berita1['probability'] = pd.Series(si3)
print(berita1)
berita1.to_csv('tes3.csv')
```

The output from that code is:

```
         title  ...            probability
0          Oppo A9 2020 Mulai Bisa Dipesan, Harganya?  ...   [0.8453283032916837]
1   Soal Bukalapak PHK Karyawan, Merger Saja denga...  ...  [0.07600105760638853]
2   BJ Habibie Meninggal Dunia, Startup Unicorn In...  ...   [0.5804913651884153]
3        Ada PHK, Ini Jumlah Total Karyawan Bukalapak  ...  [0.04687216189109762]
```

How to round value of probability, So, I expect the output of probability to be:

```
85
8
58
5
```

Comment: `berita1['probability'] = berita1['probability'].round(2) * 100`

Comment: @CodeDifferent I got this error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133538/round-a-single-column-in-pandas

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to change the probability to a percentage and round up:

```
berita1['probability'] = berita1['probability'].apply(lambda x: round(x[0]*100))
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It gives me iteration the same value in row

Comment: Try: berita1['probability'].apply(lambda x: round(x[0]*100))

Comment: The result still not multiply by 100 ` [0.6850458372469185]`

Comment: Can you double check that your `probability` column is a list of lists? i.e. every row returns a list with 1 value? *Updated answer*

Comment: the value is different on each row. the probability column is a list

Comment: So when you make the probability column, you pass in a single list, or a list of lists? Your example in the original post passed in a list of lists, so every row's probability value has to be unpacked. When I copy your code and run my function above, I get the answer you desire. So I think this may be a case of thinking your data looks like one thing, but in reality it's another thing entirely.