# How do I put numbers with different significant digits into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[1.01,2.0]})

print(df['b'])
```

Why am I getting 2.00 instead of 2.0?

And how can I put decimals with different significant digits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round a single column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133538/round-a-single-column-in-pandas)

Comment: because in `1.01` there are 2 decimal place so you are getting 2 decimal place in `2.00`

Comment: @AnuragDabas could you let me know why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[1.01,2.0]})

print(df['b'][1])
```

It will output only the value that you are concerned about. And it will output it with the same number of decimal zeroes as you entered it: `2.0`

It appears as if pandas adds decimal zeroes to some values in order to align them with the the other values in the same column.

Mathematically, there is no difference between `2.00` and `2.0`. The way humans are supposed to interpret it, is different, of course. If you want the value to be output in a certain format (e.g. via `print()` function), you can use the corresponding formatting options, e.g.:

```
print("b[0] = {:.2f}, b[1] = {:.1f}".format(df['b'][0], df['b'][1]))
```

More info about this can be found e.g. [here](https://mkaz.blog/working-with-python/string-formatting/).